# is there any way of continously reading CSV file and show it on HTML using Flask?

Tags: python

I have written a small job that takes the data from CSV and show it on HTML using Flask. It works fine but I want to automate it in a way that it starts showing any change in CSV. The CSV file is getting data from live system which means that the file content is changing with time. From my code it only shows me only show me present file and does not update for the newer content.

I have tried running bat file that will start  python script but the problem is once it is started, I need to start python again so that it takes latest CSV.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import tablib
app = Flask (__name__)
dataset = tablib.Dataset()
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'file.csv')) as f:
    dataset.csv = f.read()
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    return dataset.html    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: you would have to run JavaScript (AJAX) in browser which will periodically ask flask for new data, get them and replace in HTML in browser. Eventually you can use HTML tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">` which wil reload full page every  3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file within your index function.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    dataset = tablib.Dataset()
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'file.csv')) as f:
        dataset.csv = f.read()
    return dataset.html
```

Comment: Please accept the answer as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.